# Unable to reach pod service from kubernetes master node , from worker nodes it is working

Tags: kubernetes

I have done a fresh kubernetes installation in my vm setup .I have two centos-8 servers which are master and slave. both are configured with 'network bridged'. kubernetes version is v1.21.9 , docker version is 23.0.0. I have deployed a simple hello world nodejs app as pod. these are the currently running pods
The issue Is I Can access the pod service through it's nod's IP address as http://192.168.1.27:31500/   But I'm unable to access the pod service from master node( expecting it to work in http://192.168.1.26:31500/) , can some one help me to resolve this?

there are no restarts in k8 network components and as I have checked there are no errors in kube-proxy pods

```
NAMESPACE      NAME                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE              NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default        helloworldnodejsapp-deployment-86966cfcc5-85dgm   1/1     Running   0          17m   10.244.1.2     worker-server27   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-226w7                             1/1     Running   0          24m   192.168.1.27   worker-server27   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-4cdhn                             1/1     Running   0          63m   192.168.1.26   master-server26   <none>           <none>
kube-system    coredns-558bd4d5db-ht6sp                          1/1     Running   0          63m   10.244.0.3     master-server26   <none>           <none>
kube-system    coredns-558bd4d5db-wq774                          1/1     Running   0          63m   10.244.0.2     master-server26   <none>           <none>
kube-system    etcd-master-server26                              1/1     Running   0          64m   192.168.1.26   master-server26   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-apiserver-master-server26                    1/1     Running   0          64m   192.168.1.26   master-server26   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-master-server26           1/1     Running   0          64m   192.168.1.26   master-server26   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-proxy-ftsmp                                  1/1     Running   0          63m   192.168.1.26   master-server26   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-proxy-xhccg                                  1/1     Running   0          24m   192.168.1.27   worker-server27   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-scheduler-master-server26                    1/1     Running   0          64m   192.168.1.26   master-server26   <none>           <none>
```

Node details

```
NAME              STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE          KERNEL-VERSION          CONTAINER-RUNTIME
master-server26   Ready    control-plane,master   70m   v1.21.9   192.168.1.26   <none>        CentOS Stream 8   4.18.0-448.el8.x86_64   docker://23.0.0
worker-server27   Ready    <none>                 30m   v1.21.9   192.168.1.27   <none>        CentOS Stream 8   4.18.0-448.el8.x86_64   docker://23.0.0
```

configuration of  /etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],"dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4","192.168.1.1"]
}
```

Hello world pod deployment yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: helloworldnodejsapp-deployment
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: helloworldnodejsapp
          image: "********:helloworldnodejs"
          ports:
           - containerPort: 8010
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helloworldnodejsapp-svc
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
      app: web
  ports:
    - port: 8010
      targetPort: 8010
      nodePort: 31500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form the explanation I got following details

Node IP: 192.168.1.27
Master node IP: 192.168.1.26
Port: 31500

And you want to access the app using your master node IP which is 192.168.1.26. By default you can’t access your application directly using your master node ip because the pod is present on your worker node(192.168.1.27) even when you configured NodePort it will be binded to the worker node’s IP. So you need to expose your application using the clusterIP for accessing your application using the master node IP. follow this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/) for more details.

Comment: @user1672382 is your issue resolved, revert back if you need any additional help. Upvote or accept this solution so that it will be helpful for remaining community members.